# Joomla 3.6.2 won't save HTML Tags

Tags: custom-module, editor, joomla-3.6

After upgrading to Joomla 3.6.2 I cannot save a Custom HTML module or Article with any tags. Add a link via the Tiny MCE Editor, stripped out on save. Add through HTML, stripped out on Save. Try using No Editor, stripped out on save.

I've cleared all caches and tried on different browsers with no luck.

Anybody else with this issue? Know whats going on here?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it similar to this question? http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/1105/jce-tinymce-keeps-attempting-to-fix-valid-invalid-html?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you have not set the text-filtering to "no filtering".
Go to Global Configuration -> Text Filter : set the filtering for the desired type of user to "No-filtering".[image]

Comment: Hey @pratyush. Thanks for this! Super User was set to Whitelist, not No Filtering. All fixed now!